# Starcraft 2 Oracle to charge energy

Tags: starcraft-2

I wonder if there is some way to charge oracle units which have run out of energy?

Currently I have to wait for its power to charge up naturally, which takes too long.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to increase the energy recharge rate on an Oracle.

Oracles are not combat units really, they are primarily scouting units, and have the Pulsar Beam to conduct harassment. Pulsar Beam does deal a high amount of damage, but it's fairly short-ranged, drains precious energy that could be used for Envision (or, in some cases, Revelation) and is attached to a unit that is very fragile for its cost.

In single player, one of the side effects of the cheat code: TerribleTerribleDamage (god mode) is drastically reduced energy cost and MoreDotsMoreDots disables cost checking, but I'm not sure how it works with continuous abilities like Plasma Beam. I don't see any other cheats that mention energy, and even these don't do exactly what you've asked for.